# Starcraft 2 certain cutscenes freeze on single frame but audio still plays

Tags: starcraft-2, macos

Starcraft 2 running on Mac book pro (El capitan) with AMD Radeon R9 M370X graphics card, 16 gigs of ram.

There are a few cutscenes where it plays footage on an in-game screen, but the cutscene is frozen on a frame that shows a picture with a lot of static. The audio still plays fine, and the cutscene resumes fine after the footage on the in-game screen is finished.

For example, on the cutscene titled **The Queen of Blades**, the footage that  Tychus is watching is frozen. After that footage ends, the cutscene plays fine once the camera returns to  Tychus.

This happens every time any footage is played on the in-game screen. Here is a relevant thread about the problem:
http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/19288209047

There are several other threads, but none of them have any concrete solutions and Blizzard has not acknowledged on this problem as far as I know. I have done everything, rebooting the game each time:

- Turn all graphic settings to LOW
- Put Textures to HIGH
- Change resolutions
- Turn Movies to LOW
- Toggle subtitles on/off

Nothing has worked. In addition, I believe my graphics card driver is current because the Mac has no graphics update listed for my graphics card (About this Mac -> Software Update).

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

This problem has actually been acknowledged by Blizzard, but no fix has been released yet. They suggested some steps (such as making sure permissions on your save folder are set to full access), but I see that you're on a Mac so that doesn't really apply here.

Unfortunately this problem came with the release of Legacy of the Void and for whatever reason is also causing issues with Heart of the Swarm.

I'm going to keep looking around to see if I can find anything anyone's said recently, but it's been a long time without any suggested fixes from Blizzard.

One quick question that may help: is this your first time playing Heart of the Swarm, or did you play it in the past? Additionally, have you finished the Legacy of the Void campaign, or are you still waiting to get to it?

Comment: Is it not the issue mentioned in 3.2.1 patch notes about "cutscenes being skipped"?

Comment: This is my first time SC2. I bought SC2 2 weeks ago, but began playing the game this week. I do not have the *Legacy of the Void*, only *Wings of Liberty* and *Heart of the Swarm*.